# Throw one fair coin probability -more than-exactly

Tags: probability

i have seen an exercise and it has something weird.It says we throw a coin so it will be Letters or Person.The questions are.Successive revive of a coin:
First question,find probability **exactly** 2 times until to be letter for first time.I can't use  binomial distribution because i can have a lot revive of throwing the coin.I did the tree
Second question,find probability **more than** 2 times until to be letter for first time.I did the tree but i don't think that needs.I think it is easier way

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly you mean by "successive revive of a coin"?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking.  I think, but am not sure, that you are assuming that we get $L$ or $P$ each with probability $\frac 12$ and you asking for the probability that you get the sequences $PPL$ or $PPP$ in three tosses.  Is this correct?

Comment: @joriki i mean that you can throw for ever the coin.It doesn't stop you repeat that i mean

Comment: @lulu right in three tosses, but i mean if they asking you those questions (with specific those words exactly and more than ) what answers should be ?

Comment: Well, assuming I have the right reading then just use the fact that, for independent events, probability multiplies.  Thus, for two tosses (not three as you have) you get the sequence $PP$ with probability $\frac 12\times \frac 12=\frac 14$.  And so on.

Comment: Worth noting:  saying that you need more than two tries just means that the first two tosses are both $P$.  (so I was not correct in saying that you were asking about the triple $PPP$).  Similarly, saying you want exactly two means that you are asking about the pair $PL$.

Comment: thanks a lot.If you would like answer it to accept it as answer not as commnets